# Azure AD User Login

Tags: angular6, azure-active-directory, identityserver4

At present i am using Azure AD as a login for my application, login & logout are working fine. But how to get user info from that login , how to implement role based authentication in my application.

Answer (score 0):

You have to authorize based on the claims present in the JWT token sent by Azure AD to the application. If you want to assign roles to your users and authorize them based on that, then you would have to modify the application manifest and add the custom roles (admin, manager, user) you want for the application.

Sample Manifest:

```
"appRoles": [
  {
    "allowedMemberTypes": [
      "User"
    ],
    "description": "Creators can create Surveys",
    "displayName": "SurveyCreator",
    "id": "1b4f816e-5eaf-48b9-8613-7923830595ad",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "value": "SurveyCreator"
  },
  {
    "allowedMemberTypes": [
      "User"
    ],
    "description": "Administrators can manage the Surveys in their tenant",
    "displayName": "SurveyAdmin",
    "id": "c20e145e-5459-4a6c-a074-b942bbd4cfe1",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "value": "SurveyAdmin"
  }
],
```

Now once you assign the roles to the users, Azure AD will send it as a claim "Roles" in the JWT token. Your application has to decode it and authorize based on that.

You can learn more about how to configure this in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles) and more about the claims present in the token [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-scenarios).

Comment: this solution will work for role based authorization, but how to get UserInfo like [ User ID, Email, ... ]

Comment: You have to use claims to retrieve that information as well. Check this link to see all the available claims : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#claims-in-access-tokens and you can also configure optional claims from the list here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims.